# wp_nav_menu wrapping container on it's own

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a nav menu in my wordpress theme using the following code:

**functions.php:**

```
add_theme_support('nav_menus');

if(function_exists(register_nav_menus)) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'main' => 'Main Nav'
        )
    );
}
```

**header.php:**

```
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'container' => 'nav' )); ?>
```

Here is the resultant markup that I am getting.

**Result:**

```
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/bijiness/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Expected Result:**

But this is the markup that I was expecting to come.

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/bijiness/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

So, my question here is:

1. why instead of wrapping the unordered list with nav my code wraps it with div ? and also
2. why is it adding a class **menu** to the div?

Comment: I have set it 
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'container' => 'nav' )); ?>

Is there a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add parameter in array.and also add theme location

> 'container_class'=>false
>
> 'menu_class'=>false
>
> 'theme_location' => 'main'

```
   wp_nav_menu( array('container' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'main' ,'container_class'=>false,'menu_class'=>false));
```

Comment: thanks. your answer got rid of the class but I am still getting div as a container. nav still is not appearing

Comment: still no help. div appears

Comment: please modify add_theme_support('nav_menus');
 to add_theme_support('menus');

Answer (score 2):

try this code. refer [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) for more info

```
 <?php

$defaults = array(
   'menu' => 'main',
   'container' => 'nav',
   'container_class' => 'check',
   'container_id' => '',
   'menu_class' => 'menu',
   'menu_id' => '',
   'echo' => true,
   'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
   'before' => '',
   'after' => '',
   'link_before' => '',
   'link_after' => '',
   'depth' => 0,
   'walker' => '',
  'theme_location' => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Output is

```
<nav class="check">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-883"><a href="http://192.168.1.32/wordpress/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```